# How to change an image and reset it?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to switch between images.
The staring image is "Standing.png" and when you tap the screen it changes to "Kicking.png" then resets back to "Standing.png" after 0.15 seconds.

Is there a UIImage code or is it UIView?

Comment: Why don't you just use a UIButton with a selector, assign the starting image as the button image, on tap of button, selector changes the image to kicking and also calls a dispatch_after snippet to reset image back to standing ?

Comment: I thought about using UIButtons but i decided to go against it because it would interfere with the others.

Comment: In what way would it interfere with others? Assigning a UITapGesture to a UIImageView is almost no different to a UIButton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton *myButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"standing.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self.view addSubview:myButton];
}

-(void)buttonTapped:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *myButton = (UIButton *)sender;

    [myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"kicking.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.15 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"standing.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

add a method like this in your class

```
-(void)loadImageWithName:(NSString*)imageName
    {
       if(imageName)
          yourImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
       else
          yourImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Standing.png"];
    }
```

and in your viewDidLoad method,add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your view and call loadImageWithName method with your first image

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
         UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(changeImage:)];
         tapGesture.delegate =self;
         [self.view addGestureRecignizer: tapGesture];

         [self loadImageWithName:@"Standing.png" ];
 }
```

and in the method changeImage:

```
-(void)changeImage:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender
{

  [self loadImageWithName:@"Kicking.png"];
   NSTimer * timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.15 target:self selector:@selector(loadImageWithName:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Try this code

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
 UITapGestureRecognizer *objTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(oneTap:)];

[imageview setImageWithName:@"Standing.png" ];
[imageview addGestureRecognizer:objTap];
[imageview setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]

}

-(void)oneTap :(id)Sender
{

[imageview setImageWithName:@"Kicking.png"];

 [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.15f
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(timerM)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:NO];

}

-(void)timerM
{
[imageview setImageWithName:@"Standing.png" ];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use

```
[UIImageViewObj setImage:@"Standing.png"];
```

and then change on tap of screen that you can detect with tap gesture and set

```
[UIImageViewObj setImage:@"Kicking.png"];
```

then here, the timer will start and then in time selector method:

```
[UIImageViewObj setImage:@"Standing.png"];
```

Try it once.